# no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/categories/1')

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, spring-data

When i'm trying to pass an json request using rest api by postman i encounter an error and here is below the error log ,I'd love to know what's wrong here, I suspect its an issue with constructors knowing that i wrote the all parameters constructor and the default constructor by using AllArgsConstructor and NoArgsConstructor annotations, or that I am missing some annotation somewhere, but I am honestly unsure of where I have gone wrong.

```
o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of org.sid.cinema.entities.Categorie (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/categories/1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of org.sid.cinema.entities.Categorie (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/categories/1') at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 5, column: 17] (through reference chain: org.sid.cinema.entities.Film["categorie"])
```

this is what i wrote in postman as a json request by using this url: http://localhost:8080/films using the post method

```
{
   "titre": "my titre8",
    "description": "my descr8",
    "realisateur": "realisateur8",
    "categorie":"http://localhost:8080/categories/1"
   
}
```

here is the Film class

```
package org.sid.cinema.entities;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Film {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String titre;
    private String description;
    private String realisateur;
    private Date dateSortie;
    private double duree;
    private String photo;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="film")
    private Collection<Projection> projections;
    @ManyToOne
    private Categorie categorie;
    

}
```

here is the Categorie class

```
package org.sid.cinema.entities;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Categorie {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=75) // par defaut length=255
    private String name ;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categorie")
    private Collection<Film> films;

}
```

Comment: add your controller method

Comment: i will do it after for now my question has no relation with controller method

Comment: How do you expect to construct a `Categorie` from a `String`? That's what the error is saying and pretty clear..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a category field is a Categorie type but you are receiving a String.

It should be:

```
    {
      "titre": "my titre8",
      "description": "my descr8",
      "realisateur": "realisateur8",
      "categorie": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "XX"
      } 
    }
```